# Lighting/lightmaps with Unity 5 using Probuilder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting back into Unity again. I used to use Unity 4 to create my level where I could literally shoot out real time lights out of my gun. I used Probuilder to create my scene as well and had loads of cars and patrolling guards.
And it was smooth.

I tried to create my new game using Unity 5 and everything seems amazing. The light bounces looks fantastic. However I realized when I'm trying to bake my scene, made of 3 rooms and a hallway made with probuilder so far, it seems to take forever to bake and my baked lights doesn't seem to bake onto the Probuilder meshes. I have one realtime directional light, one mixed pointlight and a realtime spotlight.

I'm getting about 300 setpasses, about 120k verts from a small level and about 30-40 fps. Using Occlusion Culling.

I don't understand how Unity 5's lighting works now and its frustrating. All the realtime GI. Can I get some help here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use realtime GI (precomputed) all you need to do is use realtime/mixed lights and enable Realtime Global Ilumination on the Ligthing config.

Mixed lights will bake STATIC objects (make sure your probuilder models are set as static).

Check this link -> https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/introduction-lighting-and-rendering?playlist=17102